# alias の中で動的に実行したコマンド結果を使いたい

Tags: shellscript, zsh

コマンドの結果を引数にしてコマンドを実行する alias を書きたいです

具体的には特定の name のついた ec2 に SSM ログインするコマンドを書きたいので

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "api") | .InstanceId'
```

このコマンド結果を最後につけて

```
aws ssm start-session --target <ここに結果を入れたい>
```

を実行する alias を作りたいです

```
alias api-login="aws ssm start-session --target $(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "api") | .InstanceId')"
```

と定義してしまうと定義時に中身が展開されてしまって

```
api-login='aws ssm start-session --target i-xxxxxxxx'
```

となって値が固定されてしまいます
コマンド実行時に内側も実行したいのですがどう書けばいいでしょうか

Comment: `alias` の代わりに簡単なシェルスクリプト等を用意するのではダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: ダメではないです。というかそうしてるんですが環境移動するときにそのファイルも移動しないといけなくなるのでなるべく .zshrc に納められるなら治めたいです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alias を使いたければ、ダブルクォートではなくシングルクォートで囲えば良いです。`$(...)` の中身は、ダブルクォートだと文字列として評価される際に展開されますが、シングルクォートだとコマンドとして評価される際に展開されます。

ですが、このくらい複雑になるのであれば alias ではなくて shell の関数にする方がコードに説明がつけられて見やすくなりそうです。

```sh
api-login () {
    local instance_id="$(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "api") | .InstanceId')"
    aws ssm start-session --target "${instance_id}"
}
```

Comment: 素敵です！　使わせていただきます！　local とかくと環境変数も汚さずに内部だけで一時変数として使えるのですね

Answer (score 3):

ちなみにAWS CLIですが

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "api") | .InstanceId'
```

は`jq`を使わなくても

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-value,Values=api --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] --output text
```

と書けますし、タグ名をきちんと指定すると

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:タグ名,Values=api --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] --output text
```

と書けます。

Answer (score 2):

Shellじゃないのでオフトピかもしれませんが、[awscli-aliases](https://github.com/awslabs/awscli-aliases) を使って AWSCLIのAliasにする方法もあります。設定ファイルは `$HOME/.aws/cli/alias` にあるので `$HOME/.aws/config` などと一緒に管理しておけば環境移行も楽だと思います。

```
api-login =
  !f() {
    target=$(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "api") | .InstanceId')
    aws ssm start-session --target $target
  }; f
```

実行例

```
$ aws api-login

Starting session with SessionId: xxxxxx-00000000000000000
sh-4.2$ whoami
ssm-user
```